# Why there is 16 byte difference instead of 8 between two pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {    
    const char *myarr[7];

    myarr[0] = "1st array";
    myarr[1] = "2nd array";
    myarr[2] = "3rd array";
    myarr[3] = "4th array";
    myarr[4] = "5th array";
    myarr[5] = "5";
    myarr[6] = "6";

    printf("\n%p", myarr[0]);   /*00007FF749919C18*/
    printf("\n%p", myarr[1]);   /*00007FF7B3C89C28*/

    printf("\n%p", myarr[5]);   /*00007FF749919C14*/
    printf("\n%p", myarr[6]);   /*00007FF7B3C89C24*/
}
```

I commented addresses when I printed their values in the code above. Difference between the addresses stored inside 0th and 1st indexed pointers is *16 bytes*.

I thought at first it is because the string I assign them is 9 characters so more than *8 bytes*, it will not fit an *8-byte* block so it is extended to *16 bytes*. So to check this I pointed to shorted string in 5th and 6th indexes but as you see the addresses have still a 16-byte difference between them too.

As I have a *64-bit system*, shouldn't the difference be *8 bytes* between addresses 5th and 6th pointers point?

Comment: Why would you expect any particular distance between them? The string literals don't have to be stored consecutively.

Comment: The compiler is free to put the string literals anywhere in memory. Inspect the memory at address `myarr[0]` with the debugger (Debug-Windows-Memory) and you'll see.

Comment: One issue with a test such as this is that if you compile without optimization on, the compiler might be exceptionally dumb and place things far apart in the program because that's easier for debugging and/or easier to implement for the compiler implementors. While when compiling with optimization, the compiler can do clever things like merge string constants,  or just omit the strings and do something else sensible depending on the context of your code that doesn't need to reflect addresses the actual strings, and a tiny change to your code could result in different result

Comment: Also there's [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) on many OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler can store the text anywhere in the memory. So the gap between your output can't be specified.

> printf("\n%p", myarr[0]);

Will print the address of the first character of the first text, which can be anywhere.

I think what you wanted to do is

```
printf("\n%p", &myarr[0]);
```

This will print the address of the Pointer to the first Text.
So the outputs from

```
printf("\n%p", &myarr[0]);   
printf("\n%p", &myarr[1]);   
printf("\n%p", &myarr[2]);   
printf("\n%p", &myarr[3]);   
printf("\n%p", &myarr[4]);   
printf("\n%p", &myarr[5]);   
printf("\n%p", &myarr[6]);
```

will produce the result I think you were expecting.

Example output:

> 0x7ffe3bfe9a10
>
> 0x7ffe3bfe9a18
>
> 0x7ffe3bfe9a20
>
> 0x7ffe3bfe9a28
>
> 0x7ffe3bfe9a30
>
> 0x7ffe3bfe9a38
>
> 0x7ffe3bfe9a40

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to do this as you said. I wanted to see the difference between addresses of consecutive pointers.

Answer (score 12):

`myarr[0]` points to the first element of `"1st array"`

`myarr[1]` points to the first element of `"2nd array"`

They cannot *possibly* be 8 bytes apart.

But rest assured that `&myarr[1] - &myarr[0]` will be `sizeof(char*)`.

Note that your printed addresses are not 16 bytes apart: the first set differ on the 5th hexadecimal significant figure, for example.